# TypeError: destroy is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this error after using 'useContext(RobinhoodContext)' and importing useContext(that is what I think is going on). This is my code :

```
import { createContext } from 'vm'
import { RobinhoodContext } from '../context/RobinhoodContext'

const styles = {
    inputAmount: `w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center border border-white rounded-lg p-2 bg-transparent mt-6 text-white placeholder:text-white`,
    formContainer: `flex items-center`,
    select: `w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center border border-white rounded-lg p-2 bg-transparent mt-6 text-white placeholder:text-white`,
    options: `w-1/2 flex items-center justify-center border border-white rounded-lg p-2 bg-black mt-6 text-white placeholder:text-white`,
    noticeCTA: 'font-bold text-green-500 cursor-pointer mt-5',
  }

const BuyTokens = () => {
    const {
        isAuthenticated,
        setAmount,
        mint,
        setCoinSelect,
        coinSelect,
        amount,
        toCoin,
        setToCoin,
      } = useContext(RobinhoodContext)

  return (
    <form className={styles.formContainer}>
        <div className='flex h-full w-full flex-col items-center'>
            <select className={styles.select}
            value={coinSelect}
            onChange={e=> setCoinSelect(e.target.value)}
            >
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'BTC'>
                    BTC
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'ETH'>
                    ETH
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'DOGE'>
                    DOGE
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'SOL'>
                    SOL
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'USDC'>
                    USDC
                </option>
            </select>
            <select className={styles.select}
            value={coinSelect}
            onChange={e=> setCoinSelect(e.target.value)}
            >
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'BTC'>
                    BTC
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'DOGE'>
                    DOGE
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'SOL'>
                    SOL
                </option>
                <option className={styles.options} value= 'USDC'>
                    USDC
                </option>
            </select>
            <input placeholder='Amount...'
            className={styles.inputAmount}
            type='text' 
            value={amount}
            onChange={e => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button 
            className={styles.noticeCTA}
            type= 'button'
            disabled={!isAuthenticated}
            onClick={()=>mint()}
            >
                Send
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default BuyTokens
```

This is the RobinhoodContext.js file:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis";
import {
    dogeAbi,
    bitcoinAbi,
    solanaAbi,
    usdcAbi,
    dogeAddress,
    bitcoinAddress,
    solanaAddress,
    usdcAddress,
} from '../lib/constants'

export const RobinhoodContext = createContext()

export const RobinhoodProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount ] = useState('')
    const [formattedAccount, setFormattedAccount] = useState('')

    const [coinSelect, setCoinSelect] = useState('DOGE')
    const [toCoin, setToCoin] = useState('')
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState('')
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState('')

    const { isAuthenticated, authenticate, user, logout, Moralis, enableWeb3 } = useMoralis()

    useEffect(async() => {

        if(isAuthenticated) {

            const account = user.get('ethAddress')
            let formatAccount = account.slice(0,4) + '...' + account.slice(-4)
            setFormattedAccount(formatAccount)
            setCurrentAccount(account)
            const currentBalance = await Moralis.Web3API.account.getNativeBalance({
                chain: 'rinkeby',
                address: currentAccount,
            })
            const balanceToEth = Moralis.Units.FromWei(currentBalance.balance)
            const formattedBalance = parseFloat(balanceToEth).toFixed(3)
            setBalance(formattedBalance)
        }

    }, [isAuthenticated, enableWeb3])

    useEffect(() => {

        if(!currentAccount) return
        ;(async ()=>{
            const response = await fetch('/api/createUser', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    walletAddress : currentAccount,
                }),
            })
            const data = await response.json()
        })

    }, [currentAccount])

    const getContractAddress = ()=> {
        if(coinSelect === 'BTC') return bitcoinAddress
        if(coinSelect === 'DOGE') return dogeAddress
        if(coinSelect === 'SOL') return solanaAddress
        if(coinSelect === 'USDC') return usdcAddress
    }

    const connectWallet = () => {
        authenticate()
    }

    const signOut = () => {
        logout()
    }

    return (
        <RobinhoodContext.Provider
        value={{
            connectWallet,
            signOut,
            currentAccount,
            isAuthenticated,
            formattedAccount,
        }}
        >
            {children}
        </RobinhoodContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Also, this is the error:

Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: destroy is not a function

Call Stack
safelyCallDestroy
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (22831:0)

commitHookEffectListUnmount
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (22999:0)

invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25097:0)

invokeEffectsInDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27304:0)

commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27277:0)

flushPassiveEffectsImpl
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27007:0)

flushPassiveEffects
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26935:0)

performSyncWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26032:0)

flushSyncCallbacks
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12009:0)

commitRootImpl
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26910:0)

commitRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26638:0)

finishConcurrentRender
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25937:0)

performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25765:0)

workLoop
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (266:0)

flushWork
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (239:0)

performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (533:0)

I have been stuck with this for a while now. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is You are having useEffect as an Async Function ..

Please Refer For Details..  https://medium.com/geekculture/react-uncaught-typeerror-destroy-is-not-a-function-192738a6e79b

```
const asyncFunction = async () => {
      if(isAuthenticated) {
            const account = user.get('ethAddress')
            let formatAccount = account.slice(0,4) + '...' + account.slice(-4)
            setFormattedAccount(formatAccount)
            setCurrentAccount(account)
            const currentBalance = await Moralis.Web3API.account.getNativeBalance({
                chain: 'rinkeby',
                address: currentAccount,
            })
            const balanceToEth = Moralis.Units.FromWei(currentBalance.balance)
            const formattedBalance = parseFloat(balanceToEth).toFixed(3)
            setBalance(formattedBalance)
        }

}


 useEffect(() => {      
      asyncFunction()
     // or you can use it as below..
     // (async function () {
     // Function Definition
    // })();
    }, [isAuthenticated, enableWeb3])
```